# BMobilize for having mobile optimization of website?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Some say that a strong factor in SEO for a website for mobile devices is that the site must be optimized for mobile display. Is it a good solution to opt for BMobilized services? It converts your website for mobile version and stores it on their server. I just have to redirect my website to this URL if the user is looking with mobile device.

What are the Pros and CONs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious Pro's and Con's

Pro:

- No development time
- Easy

Con:

- Price (What they are providing is quite easily achievable yourself)
- Customizability
- Quality

I have no experience with BMobilized spesifically.